# Get Totals Open Documents (MySQL QUERY)

Tags: php, mysql

h ello all,

I'm trying to get $total_open_docs from while:

```
TABLE finance_folders
folder_id
folder_title
folder_status

TABLE finance_documents
document_id
document_folder_id
document_type
document_closed (0 or 1 value)


SELECT *,
document_folder_id AS total_open_docs, COUNT(*)
FROM finance_documents 
LEFT JOIN finance_folders ON folder_id = document_folder_id
WHERE document_closed = 0
GROUP BY document_folder_id


$i=0;
while ($i < $num) {
$folder_id = mysql_result($result,$i,"folder_id");
$total_open_docs = mysql_result($result,$i,"total_open_docs");
}

... table results ...

$i++;
}
```

I have 10+ records but $total_open_docs return only 2

I'm like to get results like this:

```
Folder    Open Documents
0001      10
0002      8
0003      1
0004      16
```

Any help?

Comment: you're overwriting`$total_open_docs` on every loop iteration. perhaps you want `$total_open_docs = $total_open_docs + ...` instead. and note that you're not increment `$i`, so your sample code is an infinite loop.

Comment: i have already closed loop at end, just updated below.

Comment: doesn't matter. you're still not changing `$i` inside your while() loop, therefore it's an infinite while...

Comment: `document_folder_id AS total_open_docs, COUNT(*)` looks wrong.  You mean?  `document_folder_id AS folder_id, COUNT(*) AS total_open_docs`  Makes your group statement wrong too.  Test your SQL alone first.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The query should be:

```
SELECT document_folder_id, IFNULL(COUNT(*), 0) AS total_open_docs
FROM finance_documents 
LEFT JOIN finance_folders ON folder_id = document_folder_id
WHERE document_closed = 0
GROUP BY document_folder_id
```

The alias `total_open_docs` should be assigned to the count, not the folder ID.

The PHP code should be:

```
echo "<table><tr><th>Folder</th><th>Open Documents</th></tr>";
while ($row = mysql_fetch_assoc($result)) {
    echo "<tr><td>{$row['document_folder_id']}</td><td>{$row['total_open_docs']}</td></tr>";
}
echo "</table>";
```

No need for the variable `$i` -- `mysql_fetch_assoc()` returns `false` when it reaches the end of the results. This loop is the standard idiom for processing the results of a SQL query.

BTW, the `mysql` extension is obsolete, you should convert to `PDO` or `mysqli`. But the basic structure of this loop will be the same with both.